# Android set max value as default value in number picker

Tags: android

in this simple code i want to set maxvalue for array as default to number picker. for example. in this array max value is `31` and i want to set `31` to default value but after set date my number picker have `1` value.

```
String[] month_values=new String[31];
for(int i=0; i <= month_values.length -1 ;i++){
    Log.e("I: ", String.valueOf ( i+1 ) );
    month_values[i]=Integer.toString ( i + 1 );
}

day.setMaxValue(month_values.length -1);
day.setMinValue ( 0 );
day.setDisplayedValues ( month_values );
day.setValue ( 31 );
```

Comment: Try remove -1 from setMaxValue.

Comment: why you make this simple code too complicated like for show Log value use String.valueOf() and for set month values use Integer.toString() also remove extra space from all code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

month_values length is 31 and set max value month_values length -1 which 30 try to correct code as :

```
String[] month_values=new String[31];
for(int i=0;i<month_values.length;i++){
    Log.e("I: ", String.valueOf((i+1)));
    month_values[i]=String.valueOf((i+1));
}

day.setMaxValue(month_values.length);
day.setMinValue(1);
day.setDisplayedValues(month_values);
day.setValue(31);
```

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=31; index=31`